# jQuery isotope - Style active category

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I am using the jQuery isotope plugin with hash history with jQuery BBQ.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="portfolio-categories">
   <li class="current-tab"><a href="#filter=*">All</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter=.architecture">Architecture</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter=.arts-crafts">Arts &amp; Crafts</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var portfolioContainer = $('#portfolio-container');

portfolioContainer.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.portfolio-project',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});

$('.portfolio-categories a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parents('ul').find('li').removeClass('current-tab');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current-tab');
});

// Keeps track of URL history for isotope categories
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ){
    var hashOptions = $.deparam.fragment();
    portfolioContainer.isotope( hashOptions );
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

This works great. You can link directly to the filter using the proper URL and it sorts just fine. The problem is if I click an entry in `#portfolio-container` and go back, the active state for the menu is lost and defaults to `All`, which makes sense because the `current-tab` CSS class is only applied when the category item is clicked.

Is there a way to re-apply the `current-tab` class to the item depending on what URL the filter is pointing to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into your question this afternoon hoping to find an answer but there was none. I searched around and believe I have a solution. Noticing that this question was posted 7 months ago I understand it might be a wee late.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function (event) {
     // get options object from hash
     var hashOptions = $.deparam.fragment();
     // apply options from hash
     $container.isotope(hashOptions);
 })
 // trigger hashchange to capture any hash data on init

 .trigger('hashchange');
 });

//////// styles active menu item with hash in URL
var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1); //grabs the hash from the URL
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.portfolio-categories').find('a').hasClass('current-tab')) { //finds... 
    $('.current-tab').removeClass('current-tab'); //...and removes class for active tab
    $('.portfolio-categories').find('a[href*="'+currentValue+'"]').addClass('current-tab'); //finds the hash in the 'ul a' tag and adds the class 
    // alert(currentValue); // a simple alert if you are curious what it's grabbing from the URL
    };
});

//////// menu highlight http://onepagetheme.com/isotope-menu-highlight-using-selected-class/
var $optionSets = $('.lp-option-set'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ($this.hasClass('lp-selected')) {
    return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('.lp-option-set');
$optionSet.find('.lp-selected').removeClass('lp-selected');
$this.addClass('lp-selected');
```

Demo can be found [→ here ←](http://fiddle.jshell.net/builtbymay/wZKEB/show/light/#filter=.lp-oh-la-la-date-nights) and at [→ jsfiddle ←](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/wZKEB/).

I'm sure it's not perfect but it's the only solution I could come up with. Hope it helps.